# Java ODBC and Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc, oledb

I want to access a database using a connection string that is given by a third party application. I have one example configuration that has a connection string like the following:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\path\to\theDatabase.mdb;Persist Security Info=False
```

Calling

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:" + connectionString);
```

gives me an SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

- The third party application can access the database without problems.
- The OS is Windows XP Service Pack 3 and up to date.
- The msjet40.dll in system32 folder has version 4.0.9511.0 (up to date according to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239114/en-us)
- The file exists and I *can* access it using `jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};C:\path\to\theDatabase.mdb`

I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is your MDB file in `Data Source=C:\path\to\theDatabase.mdb`?

Comment: Yes, the Data Source is pointing to the MDB file. (I've changed the path to the mdb file in my question, of course.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a problem. I don't know of any JDBC drivers for OLE DB data sources. Here on SO this questions sits without answers from March: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184046/jdbc-oledb-bin .

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem was that I thought that the connection string is an ODBC connection string, but it isn't. It is an OLE DB connection string. Therefore `jdbc:odbc:...` will not work.

Comment: The provided link doesn't exist now.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in your odbc connection
To connect access database try following

```
 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:connSource");
```

goto ControlPanel->AdministrativeTools->DataSource(ODBC)->System DSN->ADD->MicrosoftAccess->

then in the name field give the Source Name as connSource.

you have to use this name instead of database name in your DriverManager.getConnection method.

Because getConnectionMethod take the source name not the database name. so your code is not working.

Comment: I cannot do this because - as I mentioned - the connection string is given by a third party application. And according to [this site](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=87#OLEDBProviderForMicrosoftJet) the string should work.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the wesite below it contains connection strings of all variants for all the databases

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: I already found this site, but it doesn't help me. Iv'e compared the connection strings with the ones found on the site and don't see why it should not work.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I found out that the connection string **is not** an ODBC connection string but an OLE-DB connection string. The syntax seems to be the same but they are two completely different database systems...